# iOS - Can iOS app be deployed for internal company user only

Tags: ios

Is it possible to deploy an APP to apple app store, but only allow internal company user to download the APP by their own? Thanks.

Comment: Check into the Emterprise developer program. It's intended for just this sort of usage.  It is, however, limited to company employees only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with [Apple Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

> The Apple Developer Enterprise Program allows large organizations to develop and deploy proprietary, internal-use apps to their employees. **This program is for specific use cases that require private distribution directly to employees using secure internal systems or through a Mobile Device Management solution.**

Answer (score 1):

Just to augment what others have said there. The Enterprise program is what you want. It allows you to distribute your app to as many devices as you like. But as it's not going through the Apple app store, you will have to work out how you want to do it. There are third party servers out there for doing this sort of thing.

You can also simply "roll your own" by simply creating a web page on your LAN with a like to the downloadable app. The Apple documentation has the details on doing that.

Also note one difference between an Enterprise app and a app store app, is that the Enterprise app certificates will need to be renewed every year. Which means that you will need to update the app every year or it will stop working.